# Obtener elementos dentro de un div con PHP / Laravel

Tags: php, javascript, laravel

Quería saber si sería posible teniendo dentro de un div varios elementos utilizando Laravel o PHP, por ejemplo:

```
<div>
<a class="elemento">Elemento 1</a>
<a class="elemento">Elemento 2</a>
<a class="elemento">Elemento 3</a>
</div>
```

Obtener los valores de esos 3 elementos e introducirlos en un array para luego hacer una consulta a una base de datos. La intención es que un usuario pueda añadir o borrar (haciendo click sobre ellos) esos datos eligiendo de una lista, de la lista pasan a este div para que pueda visualizar lo que ha seleccionado, y luego coger esos valores y utilizarlos con la base de datos.

Gracias y un saludo.

Comment: Deberias de probar con un modelo de programación diferente:
En vez de usar solo PHP para la parte del servidor podrías usar un CLIENTE, sea JavaScript, Ajax, Angular, etc. Para lo que pretendes sería más fácil si lo implementas con eventos de dicho cliente, luego de esto puedes pasarle los valores que creas pertinente a PHP

Comment: PHP/Laravel trabajan del lado servidor,  por lo que no puedes observar los eventos del navegador, para observar los eventos del navegador puedes utilizar JavaScript y/o alguna de sus librerias, recoger los datos que necesites del navegador y/o acciones del usuario y enviarlos a Laravel

Answer (score 0):

Mira mi siguiente ejemplo:

```js
var tuArray = [];

function getElement(element){
  var text = element.textContent;
  tuArray.push(text);
  console.log(tuArray);
}

/*
Luego cuando tengas que enviar estos datos deberás enviarlos con ajax
https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp
*/
```

```html
<div>
<a class="elemento" onclick="getElement(this); return false;">Elemento 1</a>
<a class="elemento" onclick="getElement(this); return false;">Elemento 2</a>
<a class="elemento" onclick="getElement(this); return false;">Elemento 3</a>
</div>
```

Podrías probar algo de esto, nos cuentas cómo te fue.

Saludos!